# Include new header file in C4droid

Tags: android, c++, g++, header-files

I'm a beginner to C++, so please forgive me for the novice question. I want to be able to add and use Bjarn Stroustrup's header file `std_lib_facilities.h` in C4droid, but the instructions given on the google play page are too vague for me. My android device is also new and unfamiliar to me.

Where do I put the header file (which I have on my PC) to allow it to work in a simple "hello world" program? Also, what method do I use to transfer it to it's appropriate location?

Answer (score 1):

From [the guide](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/):

> Note that different compilation systems and programmer communities
>   have different conventions for where to put header files. The book
>   assumes that a header file is in the same directory/folder as the .cpp
>   files and uses "plain" #include "std_lib_facilities.h". If that
>   doesn't work, try #include "../std_lib_facilities.h" (one level up)
>   and #include "../../std_lib_facilities.h" (two levels up).